# Ошибка в коде счетчика количества простых чисел

Tags: python

Всем привет! Встала задачка. На входе число, функция возвращает количество простых чисел, меньше или равных этому числу.

Цикл получился бесконечным из-за оператора else, хотя мне казалось, в этом коде бесконечного цикла не может быть:
1) Из-за постоянного прибавления числа к переменной *x*, то есть должно сработать условие `while x <= num`

2) Из-за цикла for, где рано или поздно мы должны перебрать все значения.

Но почему он получается бесконечным? Спасибо.

```
def func (num):
#проверка на 0 и 1
    if num < 2:
        return 0

#список для хранения простых чисел
    primes = [2]

    x = 3
# х пробегает значения от 3 до num
    while x <= num:
        for y in range(3,x):
            if x%y == 0:
                x += 2
                break
            else:
                primes.append(x)
                x += 2

    print(primes)
    return len(primes)

func(100)
```

Comment: научитесь пользоваться хотя бы функцией print(), чтобы знать, чему равны переменные на каждом этапе. Чтобы else сработало, нужно до этго else дойти.

Comment: Алгоритм, кстати, какой-то странный и непонятный. Подозреваю, что на каком-то этапе перепутались x и y. В связи с этим второй совет: использовать понятные имена переменных, а не абстрактные однобуквенные криптограммы. Нечего жалеть байти, их хватит на всех.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for y in range(3,x):` в вашем случае то же, что и `for y in range(3,3):`

В свою очередь это значит `for y in []:` (крайне грубо выражаясь. range - не list)

Вы в цикл не заходите и просто вечно проверяете условие `x <= num`